# Account key vs shared access signature

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking for guidance on how to securely use azure storage in an public facing production environment.

My simplest scenarios is multiple windows 8 store clients uploading images to azure. The account key is stored in app.config.

Is it ok to distribute the account key as part of my mobile application?

Or should I have a backend service that creates shared access signatures for the container / blob?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sharing your account key in your mobile application is not desirable because the clients get complete access to your account and can view/modify other data. Shared Access Signatures are useful in such cases as you can delegate access to certain storage account resources. You can grant them access to a resource for a specified period of time, with a specified set of permissions. In your case, you want to provide  them access to only write blob content. You can find more details about SAS and how to use it here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

Comment: The part I'm struggling with is that I plan to manage access through a windows 8 app as to which blob they can access bases on grouping of meta data.  So the trade off is calls to a mobile or WCF web service  for SAS tokens. I'm also thinking the service call would have to be secured anyway. So ultimately I'm down to securing the account key on the client or securing web service calls.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I had the same issue.  I went with securing web service calls, that way I could disable access to the webservice calls to get new SAS tokens for certain users, otherwise the account key would persist forever. and only your webservice should hold secret your account key.  your account key is more important to keep secret than your SAS key.

Comment: from microsoft: "Shared access signature are keys that grant permissions to storage resources, and should be protected in the same manner as an account key. It's important to protect a SAS from malicious or unintended use. Use discretion in distributing a SAS, and have a plan in place for revoking a compromised SAS. Operations that use shared access signatures should be performed only over an HTTPS connection, and shared access signature URIs should only be distributed on a secure connection such as HTTPS."